# Python: how to cut off sequences of more than 2 equal characters in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking for an efficient way to chance a string such that all sequences of more than 2 equal characters are cut off after the first 2.

Some input->output examples are:

```
hellooooooooo -> helloo
woooohhooooo -> woohhoo
```

I'm currently looping over the characters, but it's a bit slow. Does anyone have another solution (regexp or something else)

EDIT: current code:

```
word_new = ""
        for i in range(0,len(word)-2):    
            if not word[i] == word[i+1] == word[i+2]:
                word_new = word_new+word[i]
        for i in range(len(word)-2,len(word)):
            word_new = word_new + word[i]
```

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit: after applying helpful comments**

```
import re

def ReplaceThreeOrMore(s):
    # pattern to look for three or more repetitions of any character, including
    # newlines.
    pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{2,}", re.DOTALL) 
    return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", s)
```

---

*(original response here)* 
Try something like this:

```
import re

# look for a character followed by at least one repetition of itself.
pattern = re.compile(r"(\w)\1+")

# a function to perform the substitution we need:
def repl(matchObj):
   char = matchObj.group(1)
   return "%s%s" % (char, char)

>>> pattern.sub(repl, "Foooooooooootball")
'Football'
```

Comment: You can use this pattern `(\w)\1{2,}` to match just those characters that are in group of 3 or more. You pattern hits pairs too.

Comment: I think you meant `pattern.sub(repl, "Foooooooooootball")` in the last line, but other than that, great code!

Comment: @Edo -- thanks for the catch; corrected. @alpha-mouse - true, but effectively a no-op. (replaces a pair with the same pair)

Comment: Thanks! that was what I was looking for. I havent really used regular expressions much. Could you tell me what the \1 means?

Comment: @Bart - The `\1` basically means 'what was found in group 1' and it will be the character that was found.

Comment: Ok. And in this case group 1 is the group of characters denoted by (\w)?

Comment: `\w` is just a single character, which will match ANY character, and is stored in group 1 (the group only has one character in it, but its still considered a group). The next part of the expression, `\1+`, says 'find that character repeated at least 1 more time immediately afterwords' which will result in the regular expression only matching if the character is repeated at least twice. I hope that clears it up :).

Comment: @bgporter: Yuk. -4. (1) `\w` should be `.` with re.DOTALL flag to do what the OP wants (**ANY** character) (2) `"%s%s" % (char, char)` is astonishing; try `char * 2` (3) replacing a pair by the same pair is NOT a no-op when it comes to speed; suggestion by @alpha-mouse should not be dismissed. (4) Using a function as the replacement instead of `\1\1`.

Comment: @John -- (1) & (2) are good points. (3) -- when the OP starts sitting down with a profiler and optimizing for speed, sure. Teaching someone just learning that trying to microoptimize without regard for measured performance (seriously -- you can say that that's a net positive in all cases? Spare me.) leads to a lot of the crappy code that I see... (4) yep. But when he tries to do something more complicated than this, he'll know how to do so. Trying to teach a man to fish, sir.

Comment: @bgporter: (3) Nothing to do with optimisation, except that you said it was a "no-op". Teach the OP to code exactly what he wants (replace sequences of **more than 2**) rather than do something else and rely on a a happy concidence for it not to stuff up, and spare us the post-hoc justification. (4) Introduce him to hook line and sinker first; a badly-coded stun-grenade is not appropriate for the first lesson.

Answer (score 2):

The following code (unlike other regexp-based answers) does exactly what you say that you want: replace all sequences of more than 2 equal characters by 2 of the same.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'the numberr offf\n\n\n\ntheeee beast is 666 ...'
>>> pattern = r'(.)\1{2,}'
>>> repl = r'\1\1'
>>> re.sub(pattern, repl, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
'the numberr off\n\nthee beast is 66 ..'
>>>
```

You may not really want to apply this treatment to some or all of: digits, punctuation, spaces, tabs, newlines etcccc. In that case you need to replace the `.` by a more restrictive sub-pattern.

For example:

ASCII letters: `[A-Za-z]`

Any letters, depending on the locale: `[^\W\d_]` in conjunction with the re.LOCALE flag

Comment: You're right, I need to replace more than just ascii characters. Probably ascii+punctuation, but I haven't decided yet. Now I know how to do it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also using a regex, but without a function:

```
import re

expr = r'(.)\1{3,}'
replace_by = r'\1\1'

mystr1 = 'hellooooooo'
print re.sub(expr, replace_by, mystr1)

mystr2 = 'woooohhooooo'
print re.sub(expr, replace_by, mystr2)
```

Comment: This doesn't work on sequences of exactly three identical characters, and doesn't attack newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know python regexp but you could adapt this one:

```
s/((.)\2)\2+/$1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

I post my code, it's not **regex** but since you mentioned "or something else"...

```
def removeD(input):
if len(input) < 3: return input

output = input[0:2]
for i in range (2, len(input)):
    if not input[i] == input[i-1] == input[i-2]:
        output += input[i]

return output
```

is not as bgporter's one (no joke, I really like it more than mine!) but - at least on my system - `time` report that it performs always faster.